# Progress Dialog for Fragment Transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog

I'm unable to display a progress dialog for a fragment transaction which does a lot of work. The current way that I' trying to achieve this is:

Main Activity onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 Fragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container,myFragment).commit();
}
```

And in my fragment class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

public MyFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "title", "msg");
   mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
   mProgressDialog.show();

   // Time taking code 

   mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

This is just showing a black screen until the task is completed.

Comment: Put your time taking code in non-UI thread and everything would work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time taking work should be done on a background thread. You can do it like this:

```
@Override  
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "title", "msg");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // TODO: your time taking code runs here.

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // close the progress dialog.
                        progressDialog.dismiss();                           
                    }
                });
            }

        }.start();    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AsyncTask` to do time-consuming job and show the dialog in `onPreExecute` , dimiss it in `onPostExcute`.